# How to persist data in H2 Database after node redeployment in Corda?

Tags: corda

I want to persist data in Corda H2 database after Node Deployment . The data got wiped out when I redeploy the nodes again .
Is there any way that my data got persistent even after I make changes in my node and deploy them ?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run `gradlew deployNodes`, the node folders will be deleted and re-created, removing your data. However, there is no need to constantly re-deploy the nodes.

If you want to make changes to your nodes' configuration, simply edit the nodes' `node.conf` files, as described here: https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html.

If you want to make changes to your CorDapp, you can do the following:

- Make the required changes to your CorDapp's code
- Run `gradlew jar` from the root of your CorDapp project to create an updated JAR for your CorDapp
- Copy the new CorDapp JAR from the `build/libs` folder to each node's `plugins`/`cordapps` folder
- Restarting the node's Java process

Comment: Hi Joel thanks .. Now what I am doing is just replacing the persistence.mv.db to newly deployed nodes and I am getting the previous data . But is it a correct way ?

Comment: That's fine. But I'd recommend recreating the CorDapp plugin and adding that to the existing node folder. This is how things would work with a real, long-running node.

Comment: Hi Joel while persisting data  I am getting pagination issue after 200 transactions , is there any limitation on number of records I can persist in my H2 instance .