# changes in cordapp not reflected

Tags: corda

using [How to persist data in H2 Database after node redeployment in Corda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251932/how-to-persist-data-in-h2-database-after-node-redeployment-in-corda) I did some changes in cordapp and update the jar in respective nodes by generate jar using gradlew jar. But my changes was not got reflected.

Comment: Did you restart the nodes?

Comment: how to restart the nodes? its also kind of redeployment right?

Comment: Shut down the Java process and start it again. For example, you can type `bye` in the node shell or use `CTRL + D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to restart your node's Java process to load the new CorDapps.

You can stop your node by typing `bye` in the node shell (https://docs.corda.net/shell.html) or issue a CTRL + D command to the Java process. Then restart your node as normal.

In the future, we will implement hot-reloading of CorDapps on the node.

Comment: Is this feature currently available in the Enterprise Corda which is out now?

Comment: No, this feature is not yet available.